# What can I do with super salty cream cheese mixture?

Tags: salt

I whipped up a cream cheese filling for sweet bread. By accident, I added salt instead of sugar... an entire cup. Now I have disgustingly salty mixture of 16 oz cream cheese (2 packages), two eggs, six tablespoons of AP flour, and a cup of salt. I'd prefer not to waste it. Any ideas? Maybe lots of spinach and more eggs and bake it quiche style? Or do you think it's beyond salvaging? Worried it might take an absurd amount of salt-free added ingredients to adjust for the entire cup of salt.

Answer (score 8):

This is too salty to be worth salvaging. You *could* use small quantities of the mixture in place of salt in recipes where the cheese would be complementary. But since it is so salty you cannot use very much; it would take weeks to get through it all. Salt is pretty cheap, so instead, I would just discard the mixture.

To go with your quiche idea, take a look at a [few](https://www.kingarthurbaking.com/recipes/mushroom-cheddar-quiche-recipe) [recipes](https://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/everything-bagel-quiche). They use between 1 and 2 teaspons of salt for a single large quiche. Since you have a cup of salt to deal with, this is 48 teaspoons, or at least 24 quiches! I assume you do not want to bake this many.

Comment: Agree with this answer, but if you come up with a baked quiche or dip recipe you legitimately like... Make however many, freeze it, and you just got a whole lot of Christmas presents taken care of. You could probably make some nice cheese bread with it too. Or add a lot of flour, maybe some cheddar, and roll it out for crackers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea with the spinach and eggs is probably workable, so long as you only use a little.

You could mix some of it into soups, chowders, white sauces for pasta, biscuit batters, and many other savory dishes. Maybe even gravy. I'd probably even add it to spaghetti sauce and chili, but that would be unconventional. Just don't use all of it at once (as Benjamin already indicated; use as much as you need until there's enough salt in the dish—then don't add more). With all that salt, it shouldn't go bad any time soon. So, you shouldn't need to hurry.